# Comparison of primitive projectile weapons

Tags: hunting, archery, slingshots

I have heard that there are sport hunters that practice taking game with primitive projectile weapons including long bows, slingshots, aumentum, atlatls, spears, and even throwing sticks.  I'm curious to compare the performance of each style of weapon that is being achieved by modern hunters.  Are there data on:

1. Optimal projectile weight?
2. Projectile momentum at the moment of release?
3. "Effective range," and its corollaries: *maximum range* and *accuracy*?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer will depend on the person using each weapon - different body mass and musculature will affect how effective each weapon is for each body type, so the question is unanswerable in this form.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe if we narrow the consideration to *average* or *typical* able-bodied adult hunters of the species *homo sapiens*?  I know I've seen useful population characteristics.  E.g., "What is the [average height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_height) and [weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_weight) of human adult males?"  [Data on throwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throwing).  Let's leave it open a bit: It appears there's a chance that a question of this form might admit itself to good/helpful answers.

Comment: remember, armies from history used these weapons - bows, slingshot (by circular motion rather than elastic) etc and some were specialized positions in the army. Comparison is difficult, someone who is proficient in one may not be proficient in others. There are certainly data out there on longbow draw strengths and likely momentum/fps, range etc, as there will be for other types. The use of each is specialized too - a spear is a short to medium range weapon for significant damage, whereas an arrow is longer range, but less likely to cause major damage from peripheral hits.

Comment: You may also find that this might go better on the history stackexchange.

Comment: I'm not asking about history.  I'm asking about right now: modern people, modern implementations, for modern hunting or sport.

Comment: This is not a tricky or off-topic question.  It's comparable [to this one about the accuracy that can be expected from shotguns](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/11799/6137), or [this one about the effective range of a compound bow for hunting](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/24932/6137).  There are good answers to that question, even though one could also VTC them because "the answer will depend on the person [and the] weapon...."  There is such a thing as *typical performance and proficiency* in skills and sports.

Comment: There is a whole subset of called historical re-creation where they attempt to re-create the implements. There are a ton of youtube channels (I like [Tod's Workshop](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWnlQMQ-ACfhpD68yWRsnJw)) on exactly this topic. Modern weapons are standardized for draw weight etc (as per linked q on one type of bow with specific draw weight...), so you can ask what's the effective range. Historical weapons were not. I also can't see how you can compare say a slingshot with a spear

Comment: In addition to other comments and close votes, this one is not a simple, on topic question - it is likely to be answerable only by studies or research, and SE is not a replacement for a search of historical projectile weapon studies.

Comment: This is one of the main topics of the slinging forum. http://www.slinging.org/forum/YaBB.pl